# Is this the correct use for a Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been tasked with setting up a initial application structure for a large angular application, I came across a few blog posts that basically said everything should be a directive (which I mostly agree with) but I have a feeling I have took this idea too far..

what I have got is basically  - when you navigate to `portal` ui-router will load the portal template from the templates folder, all that's inside that actual template is `<portal-view></portal-view`.. the `portalView` directive basically the entire view wrapped up in a directive.

**Route**

```
angular.module('portal').config([
'$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('portal', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "templates/portal.tpl.html"
    });
}]);
```

**portal.tpl.html**

```
<div class="container">
<portal-view></portal-view>
</div>
```

**portalView directive**

```
angular.module('portal').directive('portalView', function() {
return {
    controller: 'portalController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    templateUrl: "/directives/portalView/portalView.tpl.html"
}});
```

**portalView folder**

- portalView

  - portalView.controller.js
  - portalView.js
  - portalView.less
  - portalView.tpl.html

In my head this seems a good idea but I can it becoming a chore when we start adding more view to the application but I am hoping some angular pro will tell me this is the best way to do it :)

Any help, advice and links would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Componentizing the view and putting it into directive looks like a smart idea to me. This will ease the migration to another router also if it takes place.

`portal.tpl.html` is unnecessary if you plan to follow this practice, `template: '<portal-view></portal-view>'` would be enough. But don't reject it if you have plans on using the template for css and js asset loading (using the scripts in templates isn't straight-forward, but it is possible), it would fit the scheme quite well.

Comment: the more I think about it the better idea it seems, I think its just the fact that we have a html file with almost nothing in at the moment but I can see in the future that like you said, these template files will eventually end up having more styles ect..